# Compared to C#, Java's final is similar to const or readonly

Tags: c#, java

Wondering if compared to C#, java's final is more similar to which? const or readonly?

Comment: Maybe it's more similar to `sealed`.

Comment: @Henk With regards to adding to methods and class definitions, then yes. Java somewhat overloads the meaning with that respect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`readonly`, because just like in C#, you can only set `final` once, including within the constructor.

Answer (score 12):

Interesting question,

Java's `final` keyword implies a few things:

- You can only assign the value once
- You must assign the variable in the constructor, or as the part of the declaration

C#'s `readonly` keyword applies basically the same restrictions.

For completeness - let's look at `const`:

- You can only assign to it once as part of the declaration
- It is inherently static -- there is only one of those for all N instances of your class

So -- I'd say final is more similar to readonly.

-- Dan

Answer (score 0):

Java's final keyword implements both cases of C# `readonly` and `const` keywords.

**C# readonly**

```
public Employee
{
  private readonly string _name;
  public Employee(string name)
  {
      this._name = name;
  }
}
```

**Java final (readonly)**

```java
public class Employee
{
  private final String name;
  public Employee(String name) {
    this.name=name;
  }
}
```

**C# const**

```
public class Circle
{
   private const float Pi = 3.14F;
}
```

**Java final (const)**

```
public class Circle 
{
   private final float pi = 3.14F;
}
```

Comment: `Java final (const)` not really... `const`s  in C# by default are `static`